# IFormFile Correct Type for Image Uploading?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-2.0, iformfile

I have an asp.net core 2 api and I making a method that will accept images(maybe zip files in the future)

I am using a javascript image uplaoder called [filepond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/) and I am using IFormFile as the type.

```
  public IActionResult Import(IFormFile filepond)
        {
         //   return BadRequest();
            return Ok();
        }
```

It seems to grab data but when I look at what is stored in filepond I see

```
name = "filepond"
```

yet the file name I uploaded was like `testImage.jpg.`

I see the file name seems to be stored in

```
ContentDisposition = "form-data; name=\"filepond\"; filename=\"testImage.jpg\""
```

Is this how it should be?

Comment: You can still get the filename from the IFromFile interface FileName method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.filename?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IFormFile_FileName

Comment: That works, what is "Name" for then?

Comment: Both are optional but guess filepond likes to decorate their own name on the name tag :)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#Directives

Comment: `filepond.FileName` property value should give you the name of the file.

Comment: By default FilePond uses "filepond" as the field name, you can set this to anything you want using the `name` property or by using a file input field as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has posted the solution, I'll do it... :-)

```
public IActionResult Import(IFormFile filepond)
{
    try
    {
        var somePath = @"Ё:\Some\Path\";
        var filePath = Path.Combine(somePath, filepond.FileName);
        var stream = filepond.OpenReadStream();
        var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        fileStream.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    return Ok();
}
```